# Font Awesome (shortcut)?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I was hoping that someone could explain me the value inside the second property "content" below. From what I know it has something to do with [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome), but I can't figure out how the guy, showing this code, went from:

```css
content: @fa-var-circle-thin~@fa-var-circle-thin~@fa-var-circle-thin;
```

to this:

```css
content: "\f1db\f1db\f1db";
```

What exactly is this "\f1db"?

Comment: I think that's from the font-awesome documentation, you can use `f1db` instead of `circle-thin` in case you need the fontawesome icon in an `:after` or `:before` css element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the unicode. Its displayed under the icons, on Font Awesome's website. **Please see the example right under here.**

You will need this for making [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) in CSS.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIyyv.png)

Comment: If "unicode" is not "[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)", can you provide an explanation in your answer? (Is "unicode" something in CSS that is not related to Unicode?). If it is, can you expand it? E.g., to Unicode codepoint encoding, Unicode codepoint, Unicode character, encoding for a Unicode codepoint, encoding for Unicode codepoints, a range of Unicode codepoints, etc. (whatever it is). It doesn't have to be long. Perhaps backed up by a link.  (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: You can study it here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

Answer (score 1):

It is an encoded unicode:

```
"\f1db" => {"@fa-var-circle-thin"};
```

It is a custom unicode shortcut.

For example, if the unicode character is outside the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) range,

it should be converted to something like:

```css
content: "\{unicode number}";
```

At [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/), there will be a 4-character paragraph showing the shortcut:

[image: FontAwesome]

"\f1db Unicode: f1db"

"\f1db" is a shortcut for "@fa-var-circle-thin".

And three "f1db"'s is three "@fa-var-circle-thin"'s.

---

More about CSS unicodes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range

Comment: What is *"unicodes"*? A plural? A range? *"Unicode characters"*? *"Unicode codepoints"*? *"Unicode codepoint  ranges"*? *"Unicode character ranges"*?

Comment: Sorry, spelling improved.